# How to locally redefine __truediv__ to return Fraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, division, fractions

In Python 3, division of integers, or anything including a float, results in a float:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> f = Fraction(1, 2)
>>> f / 2
Fraction(1, 4)
>>> 2 / f
Fraction(4, 1)
>>> 1 / 2 
0.5
>>> 2 / 1 
2.0
>>> f / .1
5.0
>>> f / .2
2.5
>>> .2 / f
0.4
```

I would like to get division to return Fractions, i.e., get the following behavior:

```
>>> 1 / 2
Fraction(1, 2)
>>> 2 / 1
Fraction(2, 1)
```

I have unsuccessfully tried to redefine division:

```
>>> int.__truediv__ = lambda self, other: Fraction(self) / Fraction(other)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'
```

What are my options? I'm ok with introducing a `MyFraction` class derived from Fraction. At the least I would want to be able to define a `dict`-like class `X` such that

```
>>> X({'a': 1/3}) == X({'a': Fraction(1, 3)})
True
```

N.B.: It seems that originally, the behavior I describe was the intended one (cf. [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)):

> If and when a rational type is added to Python (see [PEP 239](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0239/)),
>   true division for ints and longs should probably return a
>   rational.  This avoids the problem with true division of ints and
>   longs losing information.  But until then, for consistency, float is
>   the only choice for true division.

Comment: You cannot. You'd have to subclass `int` (which means you won't get to use integer literals). Cast your operands to `Fraction` objects first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably shouldn't do this, but you *can* monkey-patch built-in types using the [Forbidden Fruit](http://clarete.github.io/forbiddenfruit/) module.

Comment: That's kinda awesome, and kinda terrible.  Never heard of that module, but good to know about...  And agreed, shouldn't do it.